# Is appropriate/safe for Django dashboard to be public facing?

Tags: django

I understand that Django is an ORM that you can use to build APIs and external UIs for; dashboard allows ACL access and various data-management functionality.

Is generally okay or not a good idea to allow public users to use portions of the dashboards, i.e. forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not usual, but it depends on your project and the audience of your project. I will leave you here a resume about Django book said about it, and you must decide it is suitable for your project and uses cases.

According to the [django book](https://djangobook.com/users-groups-permissions/):

> Django’s admin site uses a permissions system that **you can use to give specific users access only to the portions of the interface that they need**. These user accounts are meant to be generic enough to be used outside of the admin interface, but we’ll just treat them as admin user accounts for now. In Chapter 11, we’ll cover how to manage users site-wide (i.e. not just the admin site) with Django’s authentication system.

And on the same page ...

**When and Why to Use the Admin Interface – And When Not to**

Django’s admin site shines when nontechnical users need to be able to enter data; that’s the purpose behind the feature, after all. At the newspaper where Django was first developed, development of a typical online feature – say, a special report on water quality in the municipal supply – would go something like this:

- The reporter responsible for the project meets with one of the developers and describes the available data.
- The developer designs Django models to fit this data and then opens up the admin site to the reporter.
- The reporter inspects the admin site to point out any missing or extraneous fields – better now than later.

In other words, the raison d’etre of Django’s admin interface is facilitating the simultaneous work of content producers and programmers. However, beyond these obvious data entry tasks, the admin site is useful in a few other cases:

- **Inspecting data models.**
- **Managing acquired data.**
- **Quick and dirty data-management apps.**